# Modify table: How to change 'Allow Nulls' attribute from not null to allow null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to change one attribute in a table using T-SQL to allow nulls (not null --> null)? Alter table maybe?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio creates a very complex script for such a simple task. That's why I got confused and checked stackoverflow. Maybe that is the point of the question...

Answer (score 386, accepted):

```
-- replace NVARCHAR(42) with the actual type of your column
ALTER TABLE your_table
ALTER COLUMN your_column NVARCHAR(42) NULL
```

Comment: Or just `ALTER TABLE your_table
ALTER COLUMN your_column NVARCHAR(42)` as it will default to allowing nulls anyway if not specified explicitly otherwise.

Comment: Note if needing to change multiple columns to allow null, then you will need to perform separate `ALTER TABLE .. ALTER COLUMN ..` commands

Comment: Note there are some cases where this might not work - see [this DBA Stack Exchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27293/158) if you're getting an `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN failed because one or more objects access this column.`

Comment: @JarrodDixon I got the same error and in my case I used the wrong column type, with the correct column type it worked

Answer (score 57):

Yes you can use `ALTER TABLE` as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE [table name] ALTER COLUMN [column name] [data type] NULL
```

Quoting from the [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) documentation:

> `NULL` can be specified in `ALTER COLUMN` to force a `NOT NULL` column to allow null values, except for columns in PRIMARY KEY constraints.

Answer (score 23):

[ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123.aspx) is right:

```
ALTER TABLE MyCustomers ALTER COLUMN CompanyName VARCHAR(20) NULL
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to re-define the constraints, and just the data type? [The MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) doesn't mention that constraints would need to be redefined: "If NULL or NOT NULL is specified with ALTER COLUMN, new_data_type [(precision [, scale ])] must also be specified. If the data type, precision, and scale are not changed, specify the current column values."

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo - You are right. I was trying to be complete, but changing NULL/NOT NULL should be the only change.

Answer (score 5):

For MySQL, MariaDB

```
ALTER TABLE [table name] MODIFY COLUMN [column name] [data type] NULL
```

Use `MODIFY COLUMN` instead of `ALTER COLUMN`.

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE public.contract_termination_requests
ALTER COLUMN management_company_id DROP NOT NULL;
```

Comment: @ÁronLőrincz the question is not about Postgres though. It is tagged SQL Server so this answer is incorrect.

Comment: You're right, but it still helped me and I think it's an useful comment for people who find the question via Google. The question's title doesn't make it clear which database server it is about.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this so I could edit all tables and columns to null at once:

```
select 
case
when sc.max_length = '-1' and st.name in ('char','decimal','nvarchar','varchar')
then
'alter table  [' + so.name + '] alter column [' + sc.name + '] ' + st.name + '(MAX) NULL'
when st.name in ('char','decimal','nvarchar','varchar')
then
'alter table  [' + so.name + '] alter column [' + sc.name + '] ' + st.name + '(' + cast(sc.max_length as varchar(4)) + ') NULL'
else
'alter table  [' + so.name + '] alter column [' + sc.name + '] ' + st.name + ' NULL'
end as query
from sys.columns sc
inner join sys.types st on st.system_type_id = sc.system_type_id
inner join sys.objects so on so.object_id = sc.object_id
where so.type = 'U'
and st.name <> 'timestamp'
order by st.name
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach to do this: -

1. Check whether the table or column exists or not.
2. If yes, then alter the column. e.g:-

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
            TABLE_CATALOG = 'DBName' AND 
            TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SchemaName' AND
            TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND
            COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnName')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE DBName.SchemaName.TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName [data type] NULL
END
```

If you don't have any schema then **delete** the schema line because you don't need to give the default schema.

Answer (score 1):

So the simplest way is,

```
alter table table_name change column_name column_name int(11) NULL;
```