# Modify Sqlite Table Column NOT NULL to NULL

Tags: sqlite

I am looking for something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889916/modify-table-not-null-to-null) but I'm using sqlite3. I have tried:

```
sqlite> UPDATE JOBS SET JOB_TYPES = NULL;
```

But I got "constraint failed". Am I doing it the correct way?

I want to change the current "NOT NULL" to "NULL".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

SQLite has almost no [ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) support.

The easiest method to change a table is to create a new table, and copy the data over:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs2(..., JOB_TYPES NULL, ...);
INSERT INTO Jobs2 SELECT * FROM Jobs;
DROP TABLE Jobs;
ALTER TABLE Jobs2 RENAME TO Jobs;
```