# How can I alter my table column in Floor database with the help of Migration?

Tags: database, flutter, migration, sqflite, floor

I Want update my table column in the  [Floor](https://pub.dev/packages/floor) database with the help of changing my database version and run migrations.
For example, I want to change column A to a nullable column!
How can I achieve this goal?
anybody can provide a sample code, please?

Comment: This sounds like a github issue. you'll most probably get an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a migration like this:

```dart
//Step 1 - Update the version to (ex: from 1 to 2) inside the database annotation
@Database(version: 1, entities: [Person, Task])
abstract class AppDatabase extends FloorDatabase {

//Step 2 - create the migration
final migration1to2 = Migration(1, 2, (database) async {
  await database.execute('ALTER TABLE person ADD COLUMN nickname TEXT');
});

//Step 3 - then add it to the code that initialize the DB
final database = await $FloorAppDatabase
    .databaseBuilder('app_database.db')
    .addMigrations([migration1to2])
    .build();
```

full example of how to do it here: [Migrations in Floor](https://pinchbv.github.io/floor/migrations/)

As for actual SQL to change it from not-null to nullable check this answer [Modify Sqlite Table Column NOT NULL to NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583396/modify-sqlite-table-column-not-null-to-null)